# Invert Poisson distribution to get x based on probability

Tags: random-variables, poisson-distribution, exponential-distribution

The Poisson distribution function is given by:

`f(x) = P(X=x) = (e^(-λ) * λx )/x!`

I am writing some code and need to determine the number of events that will happen in a time step. Of course this is variable/random.

In other words:
Given our input is the standard `math.random()` value of `[0,1)`, I need to find out how many events are going to happen in time interval `t`, given that the number of events in `t` is distributed according to Poisson.

One potential solution:
With the Exponential distribution, we can find the CDF, then solve for x (invert it), and then input y, where y is `[0,1)`, and that would tell us if the next event happened in our time interval. If it did, then we would do it again for (t-x), and then, if it again happened within our time interval, we would do (t-x2), etc.

So we can invert the exponential, but I am wondering there is a way to invert the Poisson and do something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no explicit way to invert the CDF of the Poisson, but you can use the inverse CDF method anyway, you just need to loop to find the first $k$ for which your math.random() exceeds your CDF.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3693297/71809

The last algorithm in this wikipedia section does the exact same thing but is a bit smarter with the way computations are performed

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Evaluating_the_Poisson_distribution

Anyway these won't give you an algorithm that's much efficient than your exponential method. In particular both methods are linear in $t$ so if your $t$ is large there are other, better ways.

https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/14/generating-poisson-random-values/

Comment: ms excel has a cdf, but I guess it's not inverted

Comment: you say linear in t, but t is sort of continuous, so I guess maybe linear is worst case scenario (like the limit)?

Comment: The CDF itself has no explicit definition (it's a sum), and same for its inverse. Maybe excel does implement the inverse, but in the background it will compute it using the loop thing.

Comment: It's actually linear in the answer k, you go k times through the loop if you return k. So the average case running time is the expectation of k which is t. And when t is large, the Poisson concentrates around its expected value so with high probabiliy each runtime will be close to t.

Comment: where k = x? which k

Comment: Sorry, in the notation of your question, it's $x$ you are right.